# abrir uma modal e fechar a outra

Tags: jquery

tenho duas modais, so que nao estou conseguindo uma fechar automaticamente quando a outra for aberta, oque consegui ate agora foi fazer isto

**CSS**

```
.mr{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: -15%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1% 1%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: .3s;
  z-index: 9999;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ccc;
}
.show{left: 0px;}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btGeneros"><i class="fas fa-folder-open"></i></a>

<button class="btFiltro"><span></span></button>

<div class="menuG mr">
    <div class="subMenu">
      01
    </div>
</div>

<div class="menuF mr">
    <div class="subMenu">
      02
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btFiltro').click(function(){
      $('.menuF').toggleClass('show');
      $('.btFiltro').toggleClass('toggle');
      $('.btFiltro').toggleClass('black');
    })
    $('.btGeneros').click(function(){
      $('.menuG').toggleClass('show');
      $('.btGeneros').toggleClass('toggle');
      $('.btGeneros').toggleClass('black');
    })
})
```

quando a modal 01 tiver aberta, eu eu clicar pra abrir a 02, a 01 tem que fechar automaticamente, e vice e versa

Comment: Falta o resto do código para abrir as modais.

Comment: @Sam com isso elas ja abrem perfeitamente. so que se eu clicar nos dois botoes, as duas ficam abertas, uma nao fecha pra outra abrir entendeu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem que usar `.removeClass()` para remover a classe que mostra o menu. Falta também os controles da classe `.black` dos botões. E tem seletores errados também.

Deveria ser assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btFiltro').click(function(){
      $('.menuG').removeClass('show');
      $('.menuF').toggleClass('show');
      $('.btFiltro').toggleClass('black');
      $('.btGeneros').removeClass('black');
    })
    $('.btGeneros').click(function(){
      $('.menuF').removeClass('show');
      $('.menuG').toggleClass('show');
      $('.btGeneros').toggleClass('black');
      $('.btFiltro').removeClass('black');
    })
})
```

```css
.mr{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: -15%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1% 1%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: .3s;
  z-index: 9999;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ccc;
}
.show{left: 0px;}
.black{
   background: black;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menuG mr">
    <div class="subMenu">menuG</div>
</div>

<div class="menuF mr">
    <div class="subMenu">menuF</div>
</div>
<div style="text-align: right;">
   <button class="btFiltro">filtro</button>
   <button class="btGeneros">generos</button>
</div>
```

Comment: bem isso, eu tava tentando com javascript assim `$('.menuG').hide();` nao lembrava do removeClass, obrigado mais uma vez